# Jmeter is not displaying timestamp of when the http call is made in the statistics of html report

Tags: jmeter

[image]Currently in the jmeter dashboard report it shows all the requests in the statistics section, but these are sorted on a particular column. What i need is that these should be displayed in the order they are executed? How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "view results tree" or "simple data writer output" csv file to get the order of execution. HTML Dashboard will show number of requests send for each label but for order check the detail report generated in .jtl or csv format by the listerners.